# How to get avg values from input boxes with list of records using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im a beginner of js... I want to show a list of students. With this, ppl can edit directly 2 values of grade in input box,  and avg grade is auto caculate and inport to 3rd input box. I could do with 1 ppl, but 2 or more I dont know how to do.
Could anyone help me?

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/sxxfrppo/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=grade]').on('change', function() {
    var grade = 0;

    $('[id^=grade]').each(function(index) {

      grade += parseFloat($(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0);
    });

    var avggrade = $('#avg').val(grade.toFixed(2)/2);

  });
});
```

Comment: `Element.id` in `document` should be unique

Answer (score 0):

`Element.id` should be unique in `doucment`. Substitute duplicate `id`s beginning with `grade`, and `avg` with `className`s at `html`. Use `[class*=grade]` selector to select all elements where `grade` is included in `className`, `$(this).closest("tr")` to select parent element where `change` event occurs.

You can also replace ternary `$(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0` with `+this).value` where `+` operator converts string `.value` of `input` element to number.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var grades = $("[class*=grade]")
  grades.on("change", function() {
    var grade = 0;
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    $(grades, tr).each(function(index) {
      grade += +this.value;
    });

    var avggrade = $(".avg", tr).val(grade.toFixed(2) / 2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead class="">
    <tr>
      <th width="40" class="text-center">
        #
      </th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Grade 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Grade 2
      </th>
      <th>
        AVG
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        Luna
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-right grade1" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="grade1" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-right grade2" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="grade2" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-right avg" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="avg" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        John
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-right grade1" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="grade1" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-right grade2" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="grade2" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-right avg" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="avg" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sxxfrppo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using so many id's makes it quite complicated. It will only get a lot harder when the number of rows are a lot more.

To make your code flexible, you should be using a class, and some basic jQuery selector functions like closest and find.

We can assign a class "grade" to all grade input boxes and a class "avg" to the average input box.

Refer to this: https://jsfiddle.net/czvf7L9f/9/

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    Luna
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control text-right grade" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="grade1" value="" />  <!-- Add grade class -->
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control text-right grade" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="grade2" value="" /> <!-- Add grade class -->
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control text-right avg" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="avg" value="" /> <!-- Add avg class -->
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    John
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control text-right grade" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="grade1" value="" /> <!-- Add grade class -->
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control text-right grade" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="grade2" value="" /> <!-- Add grade class -->
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control text-right avg" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="0.01" name="avg" value="" /> <!-- Add avg class -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
$(function(){
   $(".grade").on("change", function() {
   var no_of_boxes = 0;
   var total = 0;
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.grade').each(function() {
       if ($(this).val()) {
         no_of_boxes++;
         total += parseFloat($(this).val())
       }
    });
    var avg = parseFloat(total/no_of_boxes);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.avg').val(avg);
  });
});
```

Comment: It already is. Besides, we  don't even need any id here. The output can be achieved using class only.

Comment: There are duplicate `id`'s within `html` at your Answer

Comment: if you take a closer look, they have used the static number "2". What if the no. of inputs are 3 or 4 instead? We should always have a dynamic solution for these things. And second, I have used 2 classes grade and avg instead of three. The best coding practice is to limit the usage of classes and id's and rely more on the selectors.